# how do I print a list in haskell?

Tags: string, haskell, io

How do I print a list to stdout in Haskell?

Let's say I have a list `[1,2,3]` and I want to convert that list into a string and print it out. I guess I could build my own function, but surely Haskell has a function built in to do that.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Indeed there is a built in function, aptly named `print`.

```
> print [1,2,3]
[1,2,3]
```

This is equivalent to `putStrLn $ show [1,2,3]`.

Comment: Following up on what @Dan said, anything that implements the Show TypeClass has a default printable representation.

Comment: How would I do it in case the list was not of standard type like Int but of custom type (Eg: type Height = Int)

Comment: @Bikash: As long as the contained type is an instance of `Show`, it will work fine. `type Height = Int` does not create a custom type, only an alias, so it behaves exactly as if you'd used `Int`s.